# Running out of memory when calling Matplotlib's pcolormesh on very large matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have a very large sparse matrix:

```
In [10]: s.matrix
Out[10]:
<19242x19242 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 393555 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

I want to visualize the matrix for finding potential clusters. When trying to generate a heatmap by running `plt.pcolormesh` on said matrix in the following fashion:

```
plt.pcolormesh(s.matrix.todense())
```

... I run out of memory. Do you have any suggestions on more efficient ways of doing this?

Comment: Maybe use `Rectangle` to only draw the non-zero squares?  `pcolormesh` is going to end up with I think 7 dense arrays the size of your input.